# PHP SQL connectivity

Tags: php, sql-server

I have manually installed Apache and PHP on my server and it has to connect to the sql server 2012 for DB. My configurations are as below:

Apache 2.4.23 VC11 x64 installed on E:\

PHP 7.0.12 VC14 x64 installed on e:\

I have installed the srv dlls from the microsoft website.( SQLSRV40.exe). Also I have installed the msodbcsql dll and the sql native client (both 64bit) , but while I run these two .exe it gets installed on to the default path which is c:\

I have enabled the php_errors and I could see that php is working fine with the phpinfo() but on the phpinfo() i dont see the sql.dll files being picked up. More over the php_error file throws the error: 
"[01-Nov-2016 12:14:58 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:/php/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

in Unknown on line 0

[01-Nov-2016 12:14:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:/php/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

in Unknown on line 0"

Am not able to figure out what went wrong, Could some one help me out, please

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the `.dll` files from `C:\` to `E:\php\ext\` (copy & paste).

Alternatively you can alter the path in the `php.ini` file which should also be in `E:\php`.

It might be helpful if you search for all files containing the text `php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64` then you know where they are actually loaded.